# Using C++ with CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm just getting started using CUDA, wondering how best to use the **host-side** API with C++.  My initial inclination with any C API is to wrap it with inline functions and methods, adding exceptions on error returns so it blends well with the rest of my code.  I've looked briefly at thrust, but that seems to be a much higher level thing, and doesn't wrap the other APIs that you may need to use.

Is there an existing wrapper that I'm missing, or is there some good reason to just use the C API directly that I've overlooked?

**Update**: I did find a library along the lines of what I was looking for called  [<Cuda> templates](http://cudatemplates.sourceforge.net/).  It's more abstract than I'd like, so I probably won't use it, but I'm putting here as a reference in case others have the same question.

Answer (score 4):

The CUDA calls will typically be closely related to kernel calls. For instance, you might allocate some memory with `cudaMalloc()` and then run a kernel on that memory. Kernels themselves, code that calls kernels (with the triple bracket syntax) and code that sets up some resources like textures, must all must be in .cu files.

Because of this, I think its best to just create small C-style libraries that wrap up the functionality related to one kernel (or a few tightly related kernels). Then, that C-style library can be wrapped up in a C++ interface if desired.

So, for instance, the C-style library may have an an `init()` call that sets up all the resources needed for a kernel to run, a `compute()` call that calls one or more kernels and a `deinit()` call that frees everything. And then, if desired, you can have a C++ class that calls `init()` in its constructor, `deinit()` in its destructor and wraps the `compute()` call with a method that checks the return value and may throw an exception.

Comment: I can see the need to encapsulate kernels and related classes, especially because of the .cu need. But why another C-style layer?  Why not a class with good exception safety?

Comment: Since kernels and textures cannot be members of a class, I guess it just seems more natural, to me, to build a C-style interface to expose those resources. That way, you end up with classes only in .cpp files and not in .cu files. But, since you can have a C++ class in a .cu file and call a kernel from the class, maybe my method is needlessly complicated.

Comment: Sometimes, it's nice to be able to write a DLL for the CUDA functionality, so that the app's dependency on CUDA is localized to the DLL. Then, it might also be a bit more natural to have the DLL expose a pure C-style interface.

Comment: Another couple of things to note... First, though C++ features are supported in .cu files, it is apparently somewhat limited what you can do. For instance, I've heard that there's some trouble with templates, so that you can't use Boost in .cu files. Second, compilation of .cu files is slow, so the development cycle might be faster if only functionality that strictly must be in .cu files is kept there. That can be facilitated by exposing the .cu functionality in simple C-style interfaces and keeping classes (with code that uses those interfaces) in .cpp files.

Comment: I'm sorry -- here's one more comment in support of the separate C-style interface and then I'm done :) Because CUDA does not come with a linker for device code, the entire tree of device functions that are called by a kernel must be in the same .cu file. So, .cu file compilation, slow to begin with, can really become painfully slow (even more so when Thrust functionality is pulled in). So, I think there's a strong case for keeping as much functionality as possible outside of .cu files.

Comment: that last point is a good one, I didn't realize the linking limitation.  However, I'm not so far having any difficulty using my own (simple) templates in .cu files, although I can see why boost could not always work, it has support libraries which often need to be linked in.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, no such thing exists. If all you want to do is throw exceptions upon error, consider using [`thrust::system_error`](http://thrust.github.com/doc/classthrust_1_1system_1_1system__error.html#details).

For example:

```
#include <thrust/system_error.h>

void my_cudaMalloc_wrapper(void **devPtr, size_t size)
{
  cudaError_t error = cudaMalloc(devPtr, size);
  if(error != cudaSuccess)
  {
    throw thrust::system_error(error, thrust::cuda_category());
  }
}
```

`thrust::system_error` derives from `std::runtime_error`. Its `.what()` member function will decode the CUDA runtime error for you:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
  int *ptr = 0;
  size_t n = 13;
  try
  {
    my_cudaMalloc_wrapper(&ptr, n);
  }
  catch(std::runtime_error &error)
  {
    std::cerr << "Uh oh: " << error.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to implement it, I just don't want to reinvent the wheel.  Your solution does add a dependency on thrust which doesn't really seem necessary, I'd rather implement a simple std::runtime_error derived class myself.  Is there a good reason to depend on thrust here?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is by no means complete. From what I remember when I was researching CUDA, the type of code you could run in those kernels is very limited. There is very little private memory space allocated to each kernel, so there can not be large stacks, heap allocated objects, and all that nice stuff that C++ is good for, which renders C++ pretty much useless for CUDA purposes. Therefore, even if there was a wrapper, it would not be practical to use due to limitations

Comment: I'm looking for a host-side wrapper, wrapping calls like `cudaMalloc`, etc.

Comment: C++ (or rather, OO), is not very useful for GPU code but not for the reasons you mention. There are CUDA functions that can adjust the amount of stack space and heap space available to a kernel. The real problem with object oriented programming on the GPU is that it does not conveniently provide fine grained control of memory access patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that. However, it is not always feasible to replace the C idioms with C++ ones right at the lowest level. For instance, doing full RAII is often inefficient: initializing an array can be substantially slower on GPU than it is on CPU, and often it's possible to e.g. design the kernels with an "unitialized" mode that replaces this costly step. You can manage this kind of stuff right in a C++ class, but IMO it's somewhat safer to put it in an extra C layer, where nobody *expects* that everything is nicely RAIIed.

Comment: I was thinking more of functions which throw exceptions on error instead of returning a code (maybe this is the C layer you mention?).  Value initialization isn't really required with RAII, as long as it's OK to have garbage scalars in your arrays, which I can live with.

Comment: By "_full_ RAII" I mean that there aren't any openly accessible garbage values. Obviously, even in normal C++ you'll sometimes sacrifice this for performance, but I like to keep it to a minimum (matter of taste I reckon). As far as exceptions are concerned: like you say, normal "weak RAII" is enough to make these safe.

Comment: RAII and designing so that resources that exist are always initialized are different things. std::vector has potentially uninitialized memory between size() and capacity(), and std::unique_ptr can have a valid allocation that points to uninitialized memory. Both of those you can use to shoot yourself in the foot just as readily as uninitialized device memory.